# Mesh disapears before out of fov

Tags: unity

I use a C# script to move the vertecies of my quad around the world space.
It works perfectly fine, but when I move/ rotate the camera away, so it does not look at the position of the quad, the quad disappears.

I cannot change the size of the quad, since that would not work with my other scritps.

How can I force the camera to allway render the mesh of the quad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you have reasons for moving the vertices rather than just transforming the quad so I won't point out how slow this way is =p.

What Unity is doing is called frustum culling, it basically checks the precalculated bounds of an object  to see if it's possibly on the screen and if not, just skips it entirely. This works fine except when the bounds don't match the vertices. That's what is happening here.

You can tell Unity to update the bounds via [Mesh.RecalculateBounds](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.RecalculateBounds.html), or if you have the information to do it without letting Unity brute force it's way through all the vertices you can manually update [localBounds and related variables in the mesh](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html).